# calculate the sum about Hashtable C#

Tags: c#

I use Hashtable and arraylist  put into some information

Now I can get some information (just like output)

```
output:

j is : 1
filekey = "1"
filename = a

j is : 2
filekey = "2"
filename = b

-----------------------------------

j is : 1
filekey = "3"
filename = c

j is : 2
filekey = "4"
filename = d

j is : 3
filekey = "5"
filename = e

-----------------------------------

j is : 1
filekey = "6"
filename = f

j is : 2
filekey = "7"
filename = g
```

Now , I want to calculate the **Count** (total number) about file[0], file[3] and j

Can tell me how to do it? thanks

```
ArrayList Allfile = new ArrayList();                   

if (name.CompareTo(Allname) == 0)
{
    Hashtable file = new Hashtable();                              

    file.Add(0, aaa);
    file.Add(1, bbb);
    file.Add(2, ccc);
    file.Add(3, ddd);

    Allfile.Add(hashtable);
    j++;

    Console.Write("j is :" +j);
    Console.Write(file[0]);
    Console.Write(file[3]);
}
```

I want it show

```
output:

j is : 1
filekey = "1"
filename = a

j is : 2
filekey = "2"
filename = b

total j is : 2
total filekey is : 2
total filename is : 2

-----------------------------------

j is : 1
filekey = "3"
filename = c

j is : 2
filekey = "4"
filename = d

j is : 3
filekey = "5"
filename = e

total j is : 3
total filekey is : 3
total filename is : 
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: How do you want to add together two strings?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I want to calculate  total number of string 
not Add Strings

Comment: @Namfuak 
I want to calculate total number of string 
Not Add Strings

Comment: So you just want the `Count`?

Comment: Also, you should use the strongly-typed `List<T>` type, and not `ArrayList`. It'll save you a ton of effort down the road, and make your code more readable for others. Same goes for `Hashtable` becoming `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. You're using, in essence, legacy types.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen YES "Count"

Comment: So you want the total count of items in each `Hashtable` in the `ArrayList`?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen If I want to calculate about "j"
HOW can I do

Comment: @TaiSH I've posted an answer. Does that answer your questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comments, it sounds like you want the total count of items in each element of the `ArrayList`. You can use LINQ for this, although you'll have to cast each element to a type since you aren't using the preferred `List<T>` type.

```
return Allfile.Cast<Hashtable>().Sum(c => c.Count);
```

You should, however, as I commented, switch from `ArrayList` to `List<T>`, and from `Hashtable` to `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. These types improve everything about your code, particularly in readability and reliability. You would also not need the `Cast` function if you changed to a strongly-typed class, like `List<T>`.

---

On the other hand, if you're just looking for the count of `Hashtable`s, you can simply inspect the [`ArrayList.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.count(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
return Allfile.Count;
```

Comment: If I want to calculate about "j" 

but I can't use j.count?

Comment: I use Allfile.Count
It show 

Allfile =1
j is : 1
filekey = "1"
filename = a

Allfile =2
j is : 2
filekey = "2"
filename = b

-----------------------------------
Allfile =3
j is : 1
filekey = "3"
filename = c

Allfile =4
j is : 2
filekey = "4"
filename = d

Allfile =5
j is : 3
filekey = "5"
filename = e

-----------------------------------

Comment: But I want to Show 

 j is : 1 filekey = "1" filename = a  j is : 2 filekey = "2" filename = b 
Allfile =2
----------------------------------- 
 j is : 1 filekey = "3" filename = c j is : 2 filekey = "4" filename = d  j is : 3 filekey = "5" filename = e 
Allfile =3
----------------------------------- –

Comment: So you just want to print the `Hashtable` counts? The code you posted in your answer is not sufficient to show what you're actually looking for. If you want to simply print the `Hashtable` counts, that's just `file.Count`...

Comment: I post the output what i want in my question