# how to join 2 String lists where Key matches and SUM with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have got 2 lists of strings that both contain `ActivityHash` i am using `.Join` to find where the hash appears in both lists and then the return the `ActivityCompletion` from the second list

**Classes**

```
public class ActivityCompletions
    {
        public string ActivityCompletion;
        public string ActivityHash;
    }

public class BungieRaids
    {
        public string ActivityName;
        public string ActivityHash;
    }
```

**Join Code**

```
var query = Activitys.Join(Completions, ac => ac.ActivityHash, c => c.ActivityHash, (activity,completion) => 
new {activity.ActivityHash, activity.ActivityName, completion.ActivityCompletion});
```

I can now return the `ActivityName` with its associated `ActivityCompletion` in a list

however i've now realised that each `ActivityHash` appears more than once so i need to `Group` these up and then `SUM` the `ActivityCompletion`

**Example Response**

```
Activityname1 = 10
Activityname1 = 7
Activityname1 = 19
Activityname2 = 5
Activityname2 = 9
```

**Expected Response**

```
Activityname1 = 36
Activityname2 = 14
```

Could anyone offer some assistance on how i could achieve this please

Comment: You shud be able to use Sum method... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902873/calculate-the-sum-about-hashtable-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're joining your two lists together correctly.  Next you need to group them by the important bits, which seems to be the ActivityName.

```
List<ActivityCompletions> Completions = null;
List<BungieRaids> Activitys = null;

query = Activitys
            .Join(Completions,
                  ac => ac.ActivityHash,
                  c => c.ActivityHash,
                  (activity, completion) => new { activity.ActivityHash, activity.ActivityName, completion.ActivityCompletion })
            .GroupBy(_ => _.ActivityName);
```

Then you'll need to project those groups to get the sum.  I am changing your Completion type to an int...

```
query = Activitys
            .Join(Completions,
                  ac => ac.ActivityHash,
                  c => c.ActivityHash,
                  (activity, completion) => new { activity.ActivityHash, activity.ActivityName, completion.ActivityCompletion })
            .GroupBy(_ => _.ActivityName)
            .Select(_ => new { ActivityName = _.Key, CompletionSum = _.Sum(__ => __.ActivityCompletion) } );
```

I would also suggest you use ValueTuples instead of anonymous classes if your framework version and C# version allow it.

Comment: Thanks very much, all combined into one :)

Comment: If i wanted to also have a totalsum of all the ActivityCompletions is it possible to do that within this method?

Comment: Yes, you could use the Sum method to project again to get the CompletionSum property.  After the select you would add `Sum(_ => _.CompletionSum);`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `GroupBy` and then `Sum` (of ActivityCompletion) in each sub groups. For example,

```
var result = query.GroupBy(x=> x.ActivityHash)
                 .Select(x=> new
                         {
                           ActivityHash=x.Key, 
                           ActivityCompletion= x.Sum(c=>Convert.ToInt32(c.ActivityCompletion)),
                           ActivityName = x.Select(c=>c.ActivityName).First()
                         });
```

Sample Input

[image] [image]

Sample Output

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i needed!, Thank you